# Changing template type depending on user input in C++

Tags: c++, class, templates, casting, stack

My assignment was to create a Stack class template so that it can be used for other data types such as int, double, string, etc. What I'm stuck on is having a declaration of type-less Stack object right before the instantiation of it with the right type. Maybe it's because I'm searching wrong but I just can't find anything on having a base class that I can convert from.

```
//in the main method
//get user input, which will be "int", "string", "double", etc.
string type;
cin >> type;

MyStack<???> stack1;
if(type == "int")
//convert stack1 to MyStack<int>
else //same thing for other data types
```

Comment: Template type arguments are resolved statically. You can't have it be open-ended and depend on a run-time value. If your set of types is limited, you can branch to different functions that use the proper type.

Comment: @StoryTeller Then would I be able to cast it to different template type at runtime by having the default template type as int?

Comment: No, the types for the cast are determined statically as well. C++ is a statically typed language. And why do you think a stack of `int` will be behave correctly when you pretend it holds `std::string`?

Comment: I am unclear how your assignment implies you need to get the above code working.

Comment: @StoryTeller Haha I was just hoping out of desperation and laziness. Then I'm guessing I should use the approach you suggested. But I'm not really getting it, can you elaborate on it?

Comment: Or declare one function template and call it. Will spare you writing the same code more than once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot.  But you can solve the underlying problem.  Here it is in [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) using continuation passing style:

```
//in the main method
//get user input, which will be "int", "string", "double", etc.
std::string type;
std::cin >> type;

[&](auto&&next){
  if(type == "int")
    return next(MyStack<int>{});
  else if (type=="string")
    return next(MyStack<std::string>{});
  else if (type=="double")
    return next(MyStack<double>{});
  else
    throw std::invalid_argument(type);
}([&](auto&& stack1){
  // Here stack1 is the correct type
});
```

this probably is not what your instructor was asking you to do.

Comment: I would love to see the look on the instructors face if this is handed in, however :)

Comment: I'll actually research on your solution and attempt to understand it. I'm very determined about finishing my project(or at least half of it)with this all-nighter. Thanks in advance if I understand it and get it working, otherwise still thanks :)

Comment: @unum No, that is the wrong response.  You wished for something, and like the devil I granted it.  Unlike the devil, I will warn you that *you do not want what you wished for*.  You have misunderstood what the assignment is asking, asked for the thing you misunderstood, and if you continue on this path you are doomed.  My hobby is doing impossible things in C++: your instructor is not asking for you to do the above.